# Comunication between server and one of three connected Client Android/Java

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, client

I have created a simple comunication beetween Server and Clients. I use TCP protocol, Socket connection. My server ( A Java program) can accept multiple connection at the same time without problem. Now my task is to do comuinicate just one of these Clients (That are Andorid Applications) with my server EVEN IF THE OTHER CLIENT ARE CONNECTED.

Let's make an example:
Client1, Client2 and Client3 are connected to my Server.

I want that Client1 send something to Client2 (but not to Client3). So my Server have to receive data from Client1 and then send the same data to Client2.

Can you advice what can be the esiest/common method?

Comment: This link may help you http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/

Comment: This may be usefull if you have a php file in the server.. My Server is a Java Application and My clients are android device. There Should be something easier than this.

Comment: Actually, `Socket`s are the (Java) way to go. What have you tried so far, or where are you actually stuck?

Comment: I created a Server (multithreaded) that can accept more then one connection. This server take data from all clients and then resend it to all Clients. This means that if  Client1 send "hello" Both client2 and Client3 will receive "hello". What I want is that if (for example) Cllient1 send "hello" , then just Client2 must receive it (and not Client1 or Client3)

Comment: Share ur code, how msg is sent to client

Comment: I have trouble modifying the thread. In anycase I use:
DataOutputSocket dos=new DataOutputSocket(socket.getOutputStream());

dos.writeUTF("Hello");

Comment: What is exactly your problem? If the server receives a message from a client and the message starts with 'send to client 192.168.0.12 then the server can do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you already provide the connections between server and client in a multi-threaded way, you could think about a little application "Hello" protocol.

If a client/server-connection is established, tell all the other clients about the new client. If a client/server connection quits, also tell them.

You could do this by sending all clients a list of all existing connections/clients.

In your android-app, you should give the opportunity to choose the recipient and on the server side, you could look in the incoming message and forward it to the client.

I made such an application with multiple bluetooth-clients a time ago and chose JSON for the messages which contained a recipient-field and the message.

As you told in the comments, your server works like this [one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/net_multisoc.htm)

A possible (but not really perfect solution) would be to write a class arround it like that (the naming is also not really good, but fits to your example):

```
public class ServerApplication {
     ServerSocket ssocket;
     static HashMap<String, MultiThreadedServer> connectionMap = new HashMap<String, MultiThreadedServer>();

     public static void main(String args[]) 
     throws Exception {

           ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(1234);
           System.out.println("Listening");
           while (true) {
               Socket sock = ssock.accept();
               System.out.println("Connected");
               //new Thread(new MultiThreadServer(sock)).start();
               Thread t = new Thread(new MultiThreadedServer(sock));
               t.start();                 
               connectionMap.put(sock.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString(), t);
           }
     }

     public static class MultiThreadServer implements Runnable {
          Socket csocket;


          MultiThreadServer(Socket csocket) {
               this.csocket = csocket;
          }


     public void run() {
         while(true) {
            //read the data and look from which client it comes
         }
     }

     public synchronized void write(String s) {
         //in this method, you can write data to the socket for a specific client
     }
 }
```

Now you have a HashMap which contains the ip-Adress of a clients (the clients) as keys and the corresponding thread where the communication takes places.

You could for example think about a Message-Class or something like that to specify which client sent the message. An example:

```
public class Message {
     String sender; //here the ip-address from the sender
     String recipient; //here the ip-adress of the client
     String message; //here the message content
}
```

With serialization-techniques (like json) you can convert such objects to strings which can be written to a socket. On the server-side, you can convert the string back to a Message-Object and decice by the recipient-field, which client should be adressed. By using the HashMap and its keys you can get the communication-thread and write the data to a specific client.

Comment: This is an intrested answer. "In your android-app, you should give the opportunity to choose the recipient and on the server side, you could look in the incoming message and forward it to the client." How can I do this? How can I forward the message just to one client

Comment: Please post something of the server-side code how you store / manage the connections to the clients.

Comment: I used this tutorial.. my server is exactly like this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/net_multisoc.htm

Answer (score 1):

The most popular solution for such a situation is using a push notification service like google GCM.
If you want to develop your solution for some reason, I suggest using "nginx-push-stream-module". using this module you can assign a channel ID to each client. then push messages to clients by providing their channel ID.
take a look at: https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module

Comment: I prefer not to use third party system. I would like to know what is the process that can make the server send data Just to ONE of the Clients connect

Comment: I have the same requirement right now and I am using nginx_push_stream_module with Websocket and it is working great, I can handle thousands of online clients concurrently. and some other guy has developed another solution using MQTT protocol: http://eladnava.com/pushy-a-new-alternative-to-google-cloud-messaging/

Comment: In fact there is no problem using this.. But the problem is that I don't know how can i do it manually. I want to learn how does it work.